# Setting every element of a node visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden

I got this: `$(element).parents('.text_place_large')`, which contains this (I verified it thanks to `alert($(element).parents('.text_place_large').html());` :

```
<div class="before_com">
  <div class="nom_util">
    <a href="1" title="Voir le profil de shidenelyu">
      shideneyu
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="mod_button">
    <a id="report1" onclick="" class="t_hideOnClickOutside" style="background-color: red; color: white;">
      !
    </a>
    <a onclick="" title="Supprimer">
      x
    </a>
    <a onclick="" title="Editer">
      Editer
    </a>
    <a onclick="" title="El button">
      Citer
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="permalink">
    Lien Permanent 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text_com">
  <p>
    Cats are sweet with salt
  </p>
</div>
<div class="after_com">
  <div class="partage">
    <img alt="Twitter" src="/assets/twitter.png">
    <img alt="Facebook" src="/assets/facebook.png">
    <img alt="G+" src="/assets/g+.png">
  </div>
  <a href="#" style="font-size: 10px">
    <abbr>
      a day ago
    </abbr>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I want to add an inline style to every tag of this node, to set them visible (for instance, `<div class="after_com">` will become `<div class="after_com style='visibility: visible;'">`)

I tried to set a loop, but it seems that I can't even get a single element.

```
$(element).parents('.text_place_large').each(function () {
  alert(this); // It returns two times '[object HTMLDivElement]'
});
```

EDIT: I have been requested more code:

```
<div class="bloc_com_contre" id="1">
  <aside>
    <div alt="\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$pseudo &lt;img style='float:right' src='img/actualise.jpg' /&gt; &lt;br&gt;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$description &lt;br&gt;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$categories\t&lt;br&gt;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMsg : $msg_count\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" class="bordure_avatar avatar_du_commentaire">
      <img alt="shideneyu" class="bigavatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/4ae4aa6bebac9381d575948b9b9cc59a?s=100&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.la-matrice.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F09%2FAnonymous.png">
    </div>
    <div class="plussoie">
      <span>
        +X
      </span>
      <img alt="Flechecontre" src="/assets/flechecontre.png">
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="text_place_large">
    <div class="before_com">
      <div class="nom_util">
        <a href="1" title="Voir le profil de shideneyu">
          shideneyu
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mod_button">
        <a id="report1" onclick="" class="t_hideOnClickOutside" style="background-color: red; color: white;">
          !
        </a>
        <a onclick="" title="Supprimer">
          x
        </a>
        <a onclick="" title="Editer">
          Editer
        </a>
        <a onclick="" title="El button">
          Citer
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="permalink">
        Lien Permanent 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text_com">
      <p>
        Cats are sweet with salt
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="after_com">
      <div class="partage">
        <img alt="Twitter" src="/assets/twitter.png">
        <img alt="Facebook" src="/assets/facebook.png">
        <img alt="G+" src="/assets/g+.png">
      </div>
      <a href="#" style="font-size: 10px">
        <abbr>
          a day ago
        </abbr>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some css:

```
.text_place_large .after_com{
  display : inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  width : 100%;
}

.text_place_large .before_com .mod_button a{
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:0.3em;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border:1px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.before_com .permalink{
   font-size: 10px;
   color: #777;
   line-height: 16px;
   margin-top: -5px;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/5c7Ts/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmydiv').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.text_place_large').children().css({visibility: 'visible'});
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe it's because what I want to set visible got their css attribute `hidden`, and not `none`
http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Why don't you include your relevant HTML for the elements you want to show in your question

Comment: What do you mean by relevant html? I can show you more JS code, but that would be unecessary. But I don't see what you mean by HTML

Comment: For example, you reference class `text_place_large` but it is not included in your question. So we cannot help you with a fiddle based on your code... since we don't know what it looks like...

Comment: I added more code, but in the edit since we wouldn't know otherwise what does my `$(element).parents('.text_place_large')` variable contains. As you notice you could have guessed where text_place_large were, it was obvious... but whatever ;)
DOn't hesitate if you need something else.

Comment: Also will need any relevant css that is hiding the elements ;)

Comment: done; please don't enlight me with a solution where you set the visibility --> manually <-- to those elements only ;)

Comment: Almost :p Check on the fiddle, permalink, as the others sub-child, don't got the visible attribute. I'm seeking a way out, I'll repost something here and accept your answer if I succeed

Comment: The solution I got is this, but it's ugly, if you got something else please
`$(element).parents('.text_place_large').children().css({visibility: 'visible'});
          $(element).parents('.text_place_large').children().children().css({visibility: 'visible'});
          $(element).parents('.text_place_large').children().children().children().css({visibility: 'visible'});`

Comment: I got what I want !       `$(element).parents('.text_place_large').find('*').css({visibility: 'visible'});` , thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You should use display:none instead of visible:hidden

Comment: There isn't any other solution? I'd like to have a jquery code to fix that.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information in my answer. What do you mean there isnt any other solution? If you use display:none in css as default if you want an item hidden you can use jquery $(element).show() and $(element).hide() to toggle between its visibility

Comment: No problem, I will consider doing this as my last resort, I would like for the time being to know how to fix it in Jquery or JS only. It took me an hour, and I would be ashamed knowing that there is no jquery/js algo to fix that, that was why I came here, even before wanting to make it work :)

Comment: Mmmh, I don't have any attribute named "visibility".
I'm seeking to add a style attribute to all my elements of my first code quote.
Between, I just changed "hidden", to "none", and my whole css is puzzled now, "none" wasn't a solution...

Comment: Oh sorry, wasnt thinking clearly, not an attribute, a style attribute can be removed by $(element).css({visibility:""}). the style attribute visibility cannot be set to "none". If you want to add a style attribute to an element. use $(element).css({styleattribute: value});

Comment: Thanks you, I want to do so... but `$(element).parents('.text_place_large').css({'visibilty': 'visible'});` doesn't work

Comment: Between, `alert($(element).html());` returns '!'
(Yes, it is the content of my link with id=report1)

Comment: Does this work -> this.css('visibility', 'visible');